# How do I return this field as a date/time so to match the input parameter's specified data type?

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I made a report in Report Builder 3.0. For the input parameter, I was struggling with the Visual Basic code to return the Monday of the current week, so I decided to let the input parameter come from a query instead.

The input parameter must be date/time so that I can give users the date/time picker on the report. Therefore, I need the query to return the Monday of the current week as a datetime data type. The problem, however, is that the resulting query keeps giving me the time portion. I only want the date. Could someone help me to strip the time portion ***AND*** still send it to the input parameter as a date/time field?

**The code:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0),1),1) MondayOfCurrentWeek
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve? You want to return datetime but want the query to return just date?

Comment: I can strip the time portion from the field in the query and it will successfully return '6/15/17' as `varchar`. But then the report throws an error because it says that the input parameter's specified data type (`date/time`) does not match the field's data type (`varchar`). This is the problem.

Comment: did you try using date instead of datetime?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan where? If you mean in the SQL code in my question, then yes, I did. But it still returned the time portion.

Comment: In the report, have you changed the parameter data type to "text"?

Comment: @CBell Yup, but I need to use the `date/time` data type there because I want to show the datepicker

Comment: CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) as DATE)

Comment: @CBell this still returns the time portion

Comment: In the field on the report or in the sql results? If it includes the time portion in the report field, right click on the field and the text box properties to the date format.

Comment: @CBell never mind, your answer worked. It looks like even though the query may return `6/5/2017 12:00:00 AM`, the report takes this as `6/5/2017`. You can submit this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to cast to date short format:

```
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) as DATE)
```